# Google map api - autocomplete for hotels

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

I try to make input field with google map api aucomplete but to search only for hotels...

I try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
          var  places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
       (
          document.getElementById('hotel')), {
        types: ['hotel']
      });
           // var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('hotel'));
            google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {
                var place = places.getPlace();
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var phone = place.formatted_phone_number;
                var name = place.name;
                var url = place.website;
                $('#address').val(address);
                $('#phone').val(phone);
                $('#url').val(url);
                $('#hotel').val(name);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

but dont work... What can be a solution here?

Comment: You might be able to use the `lodging` type, but display those results separately w/o using Google's Autocomplete library.

Comment: How can you show example ?

Answer (score 0):

This is from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch

```js
// This example uses the autocomplete feature of the Google Places API.
// It allows the user to find all hotels in a given place, within a given
// country. It then displays markers for all the hotels returned,
// with on-click details for each hotel.

// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

var map, places, infoWindow;
var markers = [];
var autocomplete;
var countryRestrict = {'country': 'us'};
var MARKER_PATH = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/images/marker_green';
var hostnameRegexp = new RegExp('^https?://.+?/');

var countries = {
  'au': {
    center: {lat: -25.3, lng: 133.8},
    zoom: 4
  },
  'br': {
    center: {lat: -14.2, lng: -51.9},
    zoom: 3
  },
  'ca': {
    center: {lat: 62, lng: -110.0},
    zoom: 3
  },
  'fr': {
    center: {lat: 46.2, lng: 2.2},
    zoom: 5
  },
  'de': {
    center: {lat: 51.2, lng: 10.4},
    zoom: 5
  },
  'mx': {
    center: {lat: 23.6, lng: -102.5},
    zoom: 4
  },
  'nz': {
    center: {lat: -40.9, lng: 174.9},
    zoom: 5
  },
  'it': {
    center: {lat: 41.9, lng: 12.6},
    zoom: 5
  },
  'za': {
    center: {lat: -30.6, lng: 22.9},
    zoom: 5
  },
  'es': {
    center: {lat: 40.5, lng: -3.7},
    zoom: 5
  },
  'pt': {
    center: {lat: 39.4, lng: -8.2},
    zoom: 6
  },
  'us': {
    center: {lat: 37.1, lng: -95.7},
    zoom: 3
  },
  'uk': {
    center: {lat: 54.8, lng: -4.6},
    zoom: 5
  }
};

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: countries['us'].zoom,
    center: countries['us'].center,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false
  });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: document.getElementById('info-content')
  });

  // Create the autocomplete object and associate it with the UI input control.
  // Restrict the search to the default country, and to place type "cities".
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (
          document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
      });
  places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);

  // Add a DOM event listener to react when the user selects a country.
  document.getElementById('country').addEventListener(
      'change', setAutocompleteCountry);
}

// When the user selects a city, get the place details for the city and
// zoom the map in on the city.
function onPlaceChanged() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (place.geometry) {
    map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(15);
    search();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('autocomplete').placeholder = 'Enter a city';
  }
}

// Search for hotels in the selected city, within the viewport of the map.
function search() {
  var search = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    types: ['lodging']
  };

  places.nearbySearch(search, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      clearResults();
      clearMarkers();
      // Create a marker for each hotel found, and
      // assign a letter of the alphabetic to each marker icon.
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + (i % 26));
        var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';
        // Use marker animation to drop the icons incrementally on the map.
        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: results[i].geometry.location,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: markerIcon
        });
        // If the user clicks a hotel marker, show the details of that hotel
        // in an info window.
        markers[i].placeResult = results[i];
        google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', showInfoWindow);
        setTimeout(dropMarker(i), i * 100);
        addResult(results[i], i);
      }
    }
  });
}

function clearMarkers() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if (markers[i]) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
  markers = [];
}

// Set the country restriction based on user input.
// Also center and zoom the map on the given country.
function setAutocompleteCountry() {
  var country = document.getElementById('country').value;
  if (country == 'all') {
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': []});
    map.setCenter({lat: 15, lng: 0});
    map.setZoom(2);
  } else {
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': country});
    map.setCenter(countries[country].center);
    map.setZoom(countries[country].zoom);
  }
  clearResults();
  clearMarkers();
}

function dropMarker(i) {
  return function() {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  };
}

function addResult(result, i) {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + (i % 26));
  var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.style.backgroundColor = (i % 2 === 0 ? '#F0F0F0' : '#FFFFFF');
  tr.onclick = function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
  };

  var iconTd = document.createElement('td');
  var nameTd = document.createElement('td');
  var icon = document.createElement('img');
  icon.src = markerIcon;
  icon.setAttribute('class', 'placeIcon');
  icon.setAttribute('className', 'placeIcon');
  var name = document.createTextNode(result.name);
  iconTd.appendChild(icon);
  nameTd.appendChild(name);
  tr.appendChild(iconTd);
  tr.appendChild(nameTd);
  results.appendChild(tr);
}

function clearResults() {
  var results = document.getElementById('results');
  while (results.childNodes[0]) {
    results.removeChild(results.childNodes[0]);
  }
}

// Get the place details for a hotel. Show the information in an info window,
// anchored on the marker for the hotel that the user selected.
function showInfoWindow() {
  var marker = this;
  places.getDetails({placeId: marker.placeResult.place_id},
      function(place, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          return;
        }
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        buildIWContent(place);
      });
}

// Load the place information into the HTML elements used by the info window.
function buildIWContent(place) {
  document.getElementById('iw-icon').innerHTML = '<img class="hotelIcon" ' +
      'src="' + place.icon + '"/>';
  document.getElementById('iw-url').innerHTML = '<b><a href="' + place.url +
      '">' + place.name + '</a></b>';
  document.getElementById('iw-address').textContent = place.vicinity;

  if (place.formatted_phone_number) {
    document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('iw-phone').textContent =
        place.formatted_phone_number;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = 'none';
  }

  // Assign a five-star rating to the hotel, using a black star ('&#10029;')
  // to indicate the rating the hotel has earned, and a white star ('&#10025;')
  // for the rating points not achieved.
  if (place.rating) {
    var ratingHtml = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (place.rating < (i + 0.5)) {
        ratingHtml += '&#10025;';
      } else {
        ratingHtml += '&#10029;';
      }
    document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('iw-rating').innerHTML = ratingHtml;
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = 'none';
  }

  // The regexp isolates the first part of the URL (domain plus subdomain)
  // to give a short URL for displaying in the info window.
  if (place.website) {
    var fullUrl = place.website;
    var website = hostnameRegexp.exec(place.website);
    if (website === null) {
      website = 'http://' + place.website + '/';
      fullUrl = website;
    }
    document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('iw-website').textContent = website;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#map {
  width: 440px;
}
#listing {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 470px;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 442px;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#findhotels {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#locationField {
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 108px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#controls {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  width: 140px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#autocomplete {
  width: 100%;
}
#country {
  width: 100%;
}
.placeIcon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 4px;
}
.hotelIcon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
#resultsTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 240px;
}
#rating {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial Unicode MS;
}
.iw_table_row {
  height: 18px;
}
.iw_attribute_name {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
}
.iw_table_icon {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="findhotels">
  Find hotels in:
</div>

<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter a city" type="text" />
</div>

<div id="controls">
  <select id="country">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="au">Australia</option>
    <option value="br">Brazil</option>
    <option value="ca">Canada</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="de">Germany</option>
    <option value="mx">Mexico</option>
    <option value="nz">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="it">Italy</option>
    <option value="za">South Africa</option>
    <option value="es">Spain</option>
    <option value="pt">Portugal</option>
    <option value="us" selected>U.S.A.</option>
    <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="map"></div>

<div id="listing">
  <table id="resultsTable">
    <tbody id="results"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div style="display: none">
  <div id="info-content">
    <table>
      <tr id="iw-url-row" class="iw_table_row">
        <td id="iw-icon" class="iw_table_icon"></td>
        <td id="iw-url"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="iw-address-row" class="iw_table_row">
        <td class="iw_attribute_name">Address:</td>
        <td id="iw-address"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="iw-phone-row" class="iw_table_row">
        <td class="iw_attribute_name">Telephone:</td>
        <td id="iw-phone"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="iw-rating-row" class="iw_table_row">
        <td class="iw_attribute_name">Rating:</td>
        <td id="iw-rating"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="iw-website-row" class="iw_table_row">
        <td class="iw_attribute_name">Website:</td>
        <td id="iw-website"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible.

The Place Autocomplete API doesn't support filtering to only hotel results.  The list of supported types for Autocomplete filtering is documented on the Google Developers site: [Types supported in place autocomplete requests](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3).  `hotel` is not in the list.

Comment: It's `lodging`.